# Rspec redirect_to follow multiple redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write a test to make sure users are redirected to the proper page after signing in. The problem however is that the user goes through two redirects before arriving at the page I want to check. Currently using `expect(subject).to redirect_to(accounts_plan_page)` stops the redirect chain at the first redirect and does not continue to the last page. So the login flow goes `localhost/signin -> localhost/ -> localhost/account/plan`. I want to test if the user gets to `/account/plan` but redirect_to stops at the root path. Is there anyway to have rspec follow to the final redirect instead of ending at the first one?

abbreviated login_spec:

```
describe 'login', type: :request do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  subject { post '/signin', { user: { email: user.email, password: user.password } } }

  it 'redirects a user properly' do
    accounts_plan_page = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/account/plan'
    if user.account.requires_metered?
      expect(subject).to redirect_to(account_plans_page)
    end
  end
end
```

This returns something along the lines of

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://127.0.0.1:3000/account/plan> but was a redirect to <http://127.0.0.1:3000/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your request spec follow redirects by using `post_via_redirect` instead of `post` to run your test.

Rspec request tests are wrappers around Rails' built-in integration tests, which have a more extensive set of [helper methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#helpers-available-for-integration-tests) you can use.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get things working nicely with this. I ended up looking at the `response.original_url` to determine if I landed on the correct page. Is this the best way to check, or is there something else?

Comment: I think that's OK. You might also look into Rspec's feature tests - they allow you to simulate a full browser interaction.